# how to expose static directories stored in aws lambda code over API gateway?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk-typescript

I am trying to serve static react app bundle using aws lambda only.
I have used a `NodejsFunction` and applied `commandHooks` during bundling to bundle a react build along with my code as shown below. I have also attached it to an API gateway as u can see.

```
  private uiLmbda = new NodejsFunction(this, "renderer", {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "..", "handlers", "ui-handler.ts"),
    handler: "handler",
    bundling: {
      commandHooks: {
        beforeBundling(inputDir: string, outputDir: string) {
          const staticAssets = path.join(__dirname, "..", "build");
          const relativePath = path.relative(inputDir, staticAssets);
          return [`cp -r ${relativePath} ${outputDir}`];
        },
        afterBundling(inputDir: string, outputDir: string) {
          return [];
        },
        beforeInstall() {
          return [];
        },
      },
    },
  });

  private scanAPI = new RestApi(this, "scan-api");
  private uiGatewayIntegration: LambdaIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(
    this.uiLmbda
  );
```

And in constructor i am calling this :-

```
 this.scanAPI.root.addMethod("GET", this.uiGatewayIntegration, {});
```

Now,i have an `index.js` as my lambda handler and a build folder with `index.html` and other refered static files as shown below.

[image]

the handler code is as shown :-

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as path from "path";

export const handler = async (event: any) => {
  try {
    console.log(path.resolve("./build/index.html"));
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "content-type": "text/html",
      },
      body: fs
        .readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"))
        .toString("utf-8"),
      isBase64Encoded: false,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

so i am able to send the html using above handler.
but not the relative files as it seems the api gateway is not aware that i wish to render subdirectories from the get method. Any help on how i can do that ? attching screenshots where u can see that main.js ( referenced through html as `<script src='/task/var/build/main'><script/>` ) gives 403 from api gateway.

[image]

Comment: Any comment on approach would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out i needed to handle this case in 2 places, one was api gateway and other was lambda handler.
I attached the lambda to serve static files using `express.static` and in api gateway i enabled proxy, and it worked.

**Edit**: oops! I think i am only returning the `index.html` from the handler, this way i can only render html, what i needed to do is check the url path from the event itself by reading `event.resource` key, and send the respective path file from the static folder, would also need to set the `content-type` header based on file extention

Comment: I wonder if we can write this without using express as a generic lambda ?